# Referencing superclass in javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

Is there a way to reference a method of a superclass while overriding that method, from another method in the subclass? I tried with `{@link super#someMethod()}`, but when I generate the javadoc, it can't find the method.

Comment: Doesn't the @Override annotation already do this job ?

Comment: You could spell out the super class name `{@link com.my.code.BaseClass#someMethod()}`

Comment: @Berger, yes, but I want to be able to reference it from other methods in the same subclass. I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Robert yeah I could, but Android Studio lets me write `super` in javadoc, and when I generate it, it has a broken link. I guess it's a fault in the IDE :/

Comment: Looks like a bug in the IDE, yes. At least I cannot find "super" being a special keyword in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html

Comment: You should put this in an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 12):

You could use inherit doc.

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
```

Answer (score 0):

`{@Link SuperClass#someMeshName()}` should do the trick